# Finding real numbers $a,b$ and vectors $v,w$ such that a condition is met with complex eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I was really confused on the following practice problem for my Lin Alg final. I worked through the idea that this question is asking for 2 real eigenvalues and their corresponding eigenvectors, but the 2 eigenvalues I got were complex numbers. Turning eigenvalues $3+i$ and $3-i$ into $a=3$ and $b=\pm1$ is where I'm very lost. Can someone explain this to me? I've shown my work below as well.

Second, after I understand where the $3$ and $\pm1$ come from, how do I find vectors that match the condition? How is this different from just finding a regular eigenvector?

[Question + My Work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22iUD.jpg)

[Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/enAGl.png)

Thank you so much!

Edit. I also noticed that the condition is of the form $S^{-1} A S$, so does this have anything to do with diagonalization?

Comment: If you understood the meaning of all calculations, you would be basically correct. But your problem is that you don't understand it. 1) You denote by the letters $a$ and $b$ both the coefficients of the quadratic equation and the coordinates of the real vector.
2) Your remark in the last paragraph of the solution has nothing to do with the solution. It would make sense to do a check instead.

Answer (score 1):

Let $u$ be a complex eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue of $\lambda$.
We have $Au=\lambda u$ and $A\bar u=\bar\lambda\bar u$ (since $A$ is a real matrix).
Now let $u=x+iy$ and $\lambda=\alpha+i\beta$,
where $x$ and $y$ are real vectors, $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are real numbers.
Then
\begin{eqnarray*}
A(x+iy)&=&Ax+iAy,\\
\lambda u&=&(\alpha x-\beta y)+i(\beta x+\alpha y).
\end{eqnarray*}
Hence it follows that
\begin{eqnarray*}
  Ax &=& \alpha x-\beta y, \\
  Ay &=& \beta x+\alpha y.
\end{eqnarray*}
Or, using the notation of your teacher
\begin{eqnarray*}
  A(x,y) &=& (x,y)\left(%
\begin{array}{cc}
  \alpha & \beta \\
  -\beta & \alpha \\
\end{array}%
\right).
\end{eqnarray*}
Now we get
$$
(x,y)^{-1}A(x,y)=\left(%
\begin{array}{cc}
  \alpha & \beta \\
  -\beta & \alpha
\end{array}%
\right).
$$